# Combining multiple data frames from yahoo finance with loop

Tags: loops, yfinance

need help to loop over data from yfinance.

I have a list of tickers that like to combine the recommendation data from yfinance but I do not how to loop it.

This is how I have done it for 3 tickers but obviously, I need help to understand how to loop it to run large data.

import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

## to use this to filter out recent 6 months data

`df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)`
`today = datetime.date.today()`
`six_months = today + relativedelta(months=-6)`

`df_msft = yf.Ticker('MSFT').recommendations[six_months:today]`
`df_aapl = yf.Ticker('AAPL').recommendations[six_months:today]`
`df_googl =yf.Ticker('GOOGL').recommendations[six_months:today]`

`df_msft['Stock'] = ['msft']*df_msft['To Grade'].count()`
`df_aapl['Stock'] = ['aapl']*df_aapl['To Grade'].count()`
`df_googl['Stock'] = ['googl']*df_googl['To Grade'].count()`

## Combine data, but need to know how to use loop instead assuming that I have 500 tickers in a list

`pd.concat([df_msft, df_aapl, df_googl])`

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to do this.

```
`appended_data =[]`
```

`for ticker in small_list:`
`table2 = yf.Ticker(ticker).recommendations[six_months:today]`
`table2['Ticker'] = [ticker]*table2['To Grade'].count()`
`appended_data.append(table2)`
`appended_data = pd.concat(appended_data)`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).